# Add if and else in javascript function to show div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a Javascript code with if and alse. Practically, I have two div that will show after selected checkbox (one and/or both) and click on link.

I'd like that for the first time divs shall go in show when click on link, starting from after first click I'd like show div only if user click on checkboxes.

I use myvariable to made this check, but seems that doesn't work.. Following the code:

```
<label for="myCheck1">Checkbox1:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" onclick="showDiv2()">
<label for="myCheck2">Checkbox2:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" onclick="showDiv2()"><br>
<a id="link-id" href="javascript: void(0)">Next</a>
<div id="text1" class="div1">Div no 1</div>
<div id="text2" class="div2">Div no 2</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
$div1 = $(".div1");
$div2 = $(".div2");

$div1.hide()
$div2.hide()

let myvariable = false;

if (myvariable == false) {

  function showDiv1() {
    myvariable = true;
    if (document.getElementById('chk1').checked) {
      $div1.show()
    } else {
      $div1.hide()
    }
    if (document.getElementById('chk2').checked) {
      $div2.show()
    } else {
      $div2.hide()
    }
  }
  $('#link-id').on('click', showDiv1)


} else {

  function showDiv2() {
    var checkBox1 = document.getElementById("chk1");
    var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
    var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("chk2");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");

    if (checkBox1.checked == true) {
      text1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      text1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (checkBox2.checked == true) {
      text2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      text2.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten your code to make it work

```js
const div1 = $(".div1");
const div2 = $(".div2");
const checkBox1 = document.getElementById("chk1");
const checkBox2 = document.getElementById("chk2");
const text1 = $("#text1");
const text2 = $("#text2");
let nextClicked = false;


$('#link-id').on('click', () => {
  nextClicked = true;
  showDivs()
})

function showDivs() {
  if (!nextClicked) return;
  
  if (checkBox1.checked) {
    text1.show();
  } else {
    text1.hide();
  }
  if (checkBox2.checked) {
    text2.show();
  } else {
    text2.hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="myCheck1">Checkbox1:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" onclick="showDivs()">
<label for="myCheck2">Checkbox2:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" onclick="showDivs()"><br>
<a id="link-id" href="javascript: void(0)">Next</a>
<div id="text1" class="div1 hidden">Div no 1</div>
<div id="text2" class="div2 hidden">Div no 2</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great code, this works!!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use if and variables like this

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $(".div1").hide();
  $(".div2").hide();
});
$("#chk1").on('change',function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.div1').show()
  } else {
    $('.div1').hide()
  }
});
$("#chk2").on('change',function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.div2').show()
  } else {
    $('.div2').hide()
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you do not understand my question. With your js code, link doesn't work

Comment: Elaborate more .

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Explain more what do u want exactly

Comment: I want that for first time, user click on checkboxes and click on link (Next) to show div. Starting from second time, if user click again on checkboxes, will be not necessary click again on link (Next), but divs shall be appear or disappear only clicking on checkboxes

Comment: okay, but what is first time and second time exactly ? how much time is between them?

Comment: same visit. First time is only before user click on link (Next). After click, 'second time' starting...